# Homotopic Loops (in the non-relative sense)

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $(X,x_0)$ is a path-connected topological space with a basepoint, what can be said about two loops $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are homotopic in the non-relative sense (the homotopy needs not to be basepoint-preserving)? Is there some nice relation between the homotopy classes $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$? I was originally thinking about what happens when you have two homotopic circular loops in the non-relative sense and ended up with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be stated even more generally, ie. suppose you have two pointed spaces $(X, x_{0}), (Y, y_{0})$. Then you can consider the sets:

- $[X^{+}, Y] = \pi_{0}(Map(X, Y))$ - the homotopy classes of all maps $X \rightarrow Y$
- $[X, Y] = \pi_{0}(Map_{*}(X, Y))$ - the homotopy classes of base-point preserving maps $X \rightarrow Y$ up to base-point preserving homotopy.

In your case $X = S^{1}$ and you are asking about the difference between loops and "free" loops. Note that there is always a natural map $[X, Y] \rightarrow [X^{+}, Y]$.

One proves (and it is not difficult), under a slight technical assumption that $(X, x_{0})$ is *well-pointed*, which is always satisfied if $X$ is a CW-complex pointed at a vertex, that:

- the map $[X, Y] \rightarrow [X^{+}, Y]$ is surjective, so any map can be homotoped to ba base-point preserving
- there is an action of $\pi_{1}(Y)$ on $[X, Y]$ such that $[X^{+}, Y] \simeq [X, Y] / \pi_{1}(Y)$

In particular, if $\pi_{1}(Y)$ is trivial (although this trivializes your case), then there is no difference between two sets. There are other criteria for proving that this $\pi_{1}(Y)$-action must be trivial, for example $Y$ being a topological group (or, more generally, an $H$-space).

If you are interested I can look for some references, but I'd believe that this is covered in most standard texts on algebraic topology.

Comment: I guess I get it. So we'd have conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ being mapped by a bijection to free homotopy classes? Thank you for your answer.