# If 2 loops with equal base points are homotopic, must they be homotopic relative to the base point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let  $X $ be a topological space and $\mathbb {S}^1$ be the set of complex numbers with magnitude 1 equipped with  the inherited topology from  $\mathbb {C} $. If we have 2 loops  $f,g:\mathbb {S}^1\rightarrow X $ such that  $f (1)=g (1) $ and $f$ is homotopic to $g $ relative to $\emptyset  $.

Must  $f,g $ be homotopic relative to $\{1\} $?

Thank you.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/370244/10014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, not necessary.

"$f,g $ are homotopic relative to $\{1\} $" is equivalent to "$[f]=[g]$ in $\pi_1(X)$".

"$f$ is homotopic to $g $ relative to $\emptyset$" is equivalent to "$[f]$ and $[g]$ lay in the same conjugacy class".

it is easy to construct an example for arbitrary $X$ with nonabelian $\pi_1$.